# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to make a working demo using Spring Boot as a Resource Server and Keycloak as an Authorization Server. Here is project code snippets:

pom.xml

```
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

App.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

AppRestController.java

```
@RestController
public class AppRestController {

    @GetMapping("/authenticated")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String authenticated() {
        return "authenticated";
    }

    @GetMapping("/permitAll")
    @PreAuthorize("permitAll")
    public String permitAll() {
        return "permitAll";
    }

    @GetMapping("/support")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('support')")
    public String support() {
        return "support";
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

I'm running Keycloak on the port 8083. Get request to the `http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/.well-known/openid-configuration` returns the following response:

```
{
    "issuer": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1",
    "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
    "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
    "check_session_iframe": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html",
    "grant_types_supported": [
        "authorization_code",
        "implicit",
        "refresh_token",
        "password",
        "client_credentials",
        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code",
        "urn:openid:params:grant-type:ciba"
    ],
    "acr_values_supported": [
        "0",
        "1"
    ],
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code",
        "none",
        "id_token",
        "token",
        "id_token token",
        "code id_token",
        "code token",
        "code id_token token"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "public",
        "pairwise"
    ],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "PS384",
        "ES384",
        "RS384",
        "HS256",
        "HS512",
        "ES256",
        "RS256",
        "HS384",
        "ES512",
        "PS256",
        "PS512",
        "RS512"
    ],
    "id_token_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
        "RSA-OAEP",
        "RSA-OAEP-256",
        "RSA1_5"
    ],
    "id_token_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
        "A256GCM",
        "A192GCM",
        "A128GCM",
        "A128CBC-HS256",
        "A192CBC-HS384",
        "A256CBC-HS512"
    ],
    "userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "PS384",
        "ES384",
        "RS384",
        "HS256",
        "HS512",
        "ES256",
        "RS256",
        "HS384",
        "ES512",
        "PS256",
        "PS512",
        "RS512",
        "none"
    ],
    "userinfo_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
        "RSA-OAEP",
        "RSA-OAEP-256",
        "RSA1_5"
    ],
    "userinfo_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
        "A256GCM",
        "A192GCM",
        "A128GCM",
        "A128CBC-HS256",
        "A192CBC-HS384",
        "A256CBC-HS512"
    ],
    "request_object_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "PS384",
        "ES384",
        "RS384",
        "HS256",
        "HS512",
        "ES256",
        "RS256",
        "HS384",
        "ES512",
        "PS256",
        "PS512",
        "RS512",
        "none"
    ],
    "request_object_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
        "RSA-OAEP",
        "RSA-OAEP-256",
        "RSA1_5"
    ],
    "request_object_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
        "A256GCM",
        "A192GCM",
        "A128GCM",
        "A128CBC-HS256",
        "A192CBC-HS384",
        "A256CBC-HS512"
    ],
    "response_modes_supported": [
        "query",
        "fragment",
        "form_post",
        "query.jwt",
        "fragment.jwt",
        "form_post.jwt",
        "jwt"
    ],
    "registration_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/clients-registrations/openid-connect",
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "private_key_jwt",
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "tls_client_auth",
        "client_secret_jwt"
    ],
    "token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "PS384",
        "ES384",
        "RS384",
        "HS256",
        "HS512",
        "ES256",
        "RS256",
        "HS384",
        "ES512",
        "PS256",
        "PS512",
        "RS512"
    ],
    "introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "private_key_jwt",
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "tls_client_auth",
        "client_secret_jwt"
    ],
    "introspection_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "PS384",
        "ES384",
        "RS384",
        "HS256",
        "HS512",
        "ES256",
        "RS256",
        "HS384",
        "ES512",
        "PS256",
        "PS512",
        "RS512"
    ],
    "authorization_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "PS384",
        "ES384",
        "RS384",
        "HS256",
        "HS512",
        "ES256",
        "RS256",
        "HS384",
        "ES512",
        "PS256",
        "PS512",
        "RS512"
    ],
    "authorization_encryption_alg_values_supported": [
        "RSA-OAEP",
        "RSA-OAEP-256",
        "RSA1_5"
    ],
    "authorization_encryption_enc_values_supported": [
        "A256GCM",
        "A192GCM",
        "A128GCM",
        "A128CBC-HS256",
        "A192CBC-HS384",
        "A256CBC-HS512"
    ],
    "claims_supported": [
        "aud",
        "sub",
        "iss",
        "auth_time",
        "name",
        "given_name",
        "family_name",
        "preferred_username",
        "email",
        "acr"
    ],
    "claim_types_supported": [
        "normal"
    ],
    "claims_parameter_supported": true,
    "scopes_supported": [
        "openid",
        "roles",
        "microprofile-jwt",
        "offline_access",
        "address",
        "web-origins",
        "acr",
        "phone",
        "profile",
        "email"
    ],
    "request_parameter_supported": true,
    "request_uri_parameter_supported": true,
    "require_request_uri_registration": true,
    "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
        "plain",
        "S256"
    ],
    "tls_client_certificate_bound_access_tokens": true,
    "revocation_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/revoke",
    "revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "private_key_jwt",
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "tls_client_auth",
        "client_secret_jwt"
    ],
    "revocation_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "PS384",
        "ES384",
        "RS384",
        "HS256",
        "HS512",
        "ES256",
        "RS256",
        "HS384",
        "ES512",
        "PS256",
        "PS512",
        "RS512"
    ],
    "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/auth/device",
    "backchannel_token_delivery_modes_supported": [
        "poll",
        "ping"
    ],
    "backchannel_authentication_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/ext/ciba/auth",
    "backchannel_authentication_request_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "PS384",
        "ES384",
        "RS384",
        "ES256",
        "RS256",
        "ES512",
        "PS256",
        "PS512",
        "RS512"
    ],
    "require_pushed_authorization_requests": false,
    "pushed_authorization_request_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/ext/par/request",
    "mtls_endpoint_aliases": {
        "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/token",
        "revocation_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/revoke",
        "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
        "device_authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/auth/device",
        "registration_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/clients-registrations/openid-connect",
        "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
        "pushed_authorization_request_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/ext/par/request",
        "backchannel_authentication_endpoint": "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/ext/ciba/auth"
    }
}
```

To get an access token, I send a post request to the `http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/protocol/openid-connect/token` with password grand type and get the following response:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJuLXRnUjJJUDdfamp6TXhqbU40XzdBSS1Temx4Yk14d3lyamtueGd0bHVzIn0.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.CZZx5tmI80qD84qg_cNjwxE13G6U_q5bm1gFFyvDAb0AZsQpckt83Vp7CyhAy40U7nHnOLaSnoVE3VbJQ65hbKLQiXqNs65GKVEaX0iBDNHGJz1WkWDtC8lox55fbgDaePNE7TGwDx15lIMkBHEdXBrMvl1Cm51Npi7nzsqmu2KdybwvnmVxcFJye3Y_OvbfRgEh2QQP4QrnIl2Qb6BuGcja3FY4SqIVEtMr-ZfXHxi3v9Az3NFWLPKPcGiQmLTVp2tYvAWsVvUWV6tomFGFFKtfaLNyXAk1ztGphPrckkGzIi_T_xKIEh56zD_egURKx0ZiDsTxgzJToRdJt6XIlw",
    "expires_in": 299,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1799,
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJhOWFkOTRlMy02ODIzLTQ0MzMtOWYyZC0xMzYzNTA3OTRhMGIifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2NjM4NDUyNDYsImlhdCI6MTY2Mzg0MzQ0NiwianRpIjoiNDc2Y2M0ZWMtYmMwYS00OTUxLTlkMmItMTk1ZmUzMGQyMzZmIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgzL3JlYWxtcy9yZWFsbV8xIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgzL3JlYWxtcy9yZWFsbV8xIiwic3ViIjoiMDI5MjRiNDQtNGZlMS00NjRmLTkzYmItY2E3MzkyZTRjNDk4IiwidHlwIjoiUmVmcmVzaCIsImF6cCI6ImNsaWVudC0xIiwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjBjYWQ2NmE4LWM0NjUtNGNjZS1hYzIxLTc3YTM0MWI1ZWEzMyIsInNjb3BlIjoicHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCIsInNpZCI6IjBjYWQ2NmE4LWM0NjUtNGNjZS1hYzIxLTc3YTM0MWI1ZWEzMyJ9.5Kb2XldpwkEKnGC9baRMDdRDLjid-SpZ1NlnZjse9OE",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not-before-policy": 0,
    "session_state": "0cad66a8-c465-4cce-ac21-77a341b5ea33",
    "scope": "profile email"
}
```

Then, I send get request to the `http://localhost:8080/permitAll` and get 401 response status and the following stacktrace in the logs:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderInitializationException: Failed to lazily resolve the supplied JwtDecoder instance
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.wrapException(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:58) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.decode(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:49) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:97) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:134) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1/.well-known/openid-configuration"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:166) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfigurationForIssuerLocation(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:79) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(JwtDecoders.java:93) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration$JwtDecoderConfiguration.lambda$jwtDecoderByIssuerUri$3(OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.java:141) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.decode(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:46) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should just be this in `application.properties`

```
 spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1
```

The issuer should match the issuer from the Keycloak configuration URL.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Spring Boot 2.7.2 and Keycloak Server Version 16.1.1 (running via docker-compose jboss/keycloak)

In my case, this URI was not working:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8083/realms/realm_1
```

But when I added 'auth' before '/realms' application started successfully:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8083/auth/realms/realm_1
```